# Apply plugin in Gradle throws NullPointerException

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using Gradle 3.5.1 in multi-module project and trying to apply `docker-remote-api` plugin to one of the modules and have following error while import Gradle changes in IDE.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:6.1.3"
    }
}     

apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'
```

And I have following error which refers to the line with 'apply plugin......'

```
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes 
precedence.
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.with(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:239)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$757.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
```

Comment: Have you tried with more recent versions of Gradle? The plugin itself is built against Gradle 5.2.1.

Comment: You right, did not noticed that Gradle 5.2.1 is minimum supported version.